# pdo->execute() results in an empty value

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

I have a condition, if you find the exact url in the table, will return true, but if you do not think will return false.

But when I run the sql and it returns empty, the condition is as if I had found this condition, I will give an example.

```
$sql = "SELECT url FROM table WHERE url = '$link'";
$prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
if ( $prepare->execute() ) {
return true;
} else {
return false; }
```

I want even when it returns empty, he gives the result of else.

If execute returns empty it feels true, but is false

Comment: can you please re-write your question, it makes 0 sense. Who is he?

Comment: Why bother using prepared statements if you don't use bind variables?

Comment: sorry about my english -.-

Comment: You need to check the manual, `execute()` returns `true` for a successful query, unrelated to the number of rows (if any...) found.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want even when it returns empty, he gives the result of else.

Well, that's not what execute does. It only returns false if the query failed. A query which is able to execute but returns 0 rows is not a failure.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

You will need to count the rows your statement would select first: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Go to **Example #2 Counting rows returned by a SELECT statement**

Comment: Good, then please mark as the answer when you can. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `execute()` indicates whether the query succeeded or failed. A query only fails if there's an error of some kind (network problems, permissions errors). If the query simply doesn't find any matching data, that's not an error, it's normal behavior, and `execute` returns `true`.

If you want to know if any data was returned, call `fetch` or `fetchAll` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bind in PDO.

It will `return false` if no data found or query not executed.You can try this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT url FROM table WHERE url = :link";
    $prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
    prepare->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    if ( $prepare->execute() ) {
     if($prepare->rowCount()){
       echo "got data";
        return true;
     }
     else{
       echo "no data";
       return false;
      }

    } else {
    return false;
   }
```

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for, however, Jessica has already answered this before, sorry = c

Comment: @Deharlan : if you think my answer is best than other you can accept it or if you think another answer is best then accept that :)